# Ford Town and Country 2008 not starting

Tags: electrical, ford, no-crank-no-start

My car won't start, I checked everything and still won't start. When I checked the fuses . The ignition fuse does not get any power.  What else can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. When you say you "checked everything", can you list specifically what you've inspected so far? Also, when you turn the key to the ACC position, do the other systems power up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your diagram, it does not show a fuse for starting, that is controlled by the ECM and BCM (computers)

It could be the relay, which is in the TIPM box under the hood. It may or may not be replaceable, if not auto parts suppliers have reman TIPM boxes for sale.

You are probably best to take it to a reputable shop for a diagnosis, the starting system is complicated and too many components can keep it from starting.

[image]